# set countdown correctly, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**How can I set my countdown correctly?**

I'm counting from 33,000.00 to zero. It works in a fashion, but the minus operator appears in the textfield.

```
//Countdown from 33,000.00 to zero
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
var count:int = -3300000; 
var fcount:int = 0; 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
timer.start();   
function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
count++;  
fcount=int(count);
mytext.text = formatCount(fcount);
}
function formatCount(i:int):String { 
var fraction:int = i % 100; 
var whole:int = i / 100;  
return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
}
```

---

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/nm___.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/nm___.jpg)

---

**EXAMPLE**
I need something I can update with XML, to be an up-counter or down-counter depending on the variables.

```
//Count up from 33,000.00
var countValue:int = 3300000;
count = countValue;

//Count down from 33,000.00
var countValue:int = -3300000;
count = countValue;
```

---

This is all I needed
fcount = Math.abs(count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the minus sign:

```
// Absolute value of i will be calculated in abs_i.
var abs_i:int = i;
if (abs_i < 0)
    abs_i = -abs_i;

var fraction:int = abs_i % 100; 
var whole:int = abs_i / 100;
```

To handle the case where you wish to count up, you will have to do things a bit differently.  It would be better to have two functions, including a new function named decrementCounter.  If you like, there can be an event handler which uses an `if (counter < 0)` to determine which should be called.

EDIT: On re-reading your code it seems you intended

```
fcount=int(count)
```

might solve your problem, but you could call

```
fcount = Math.abs(count)
```

and then your "formatted count" would always be a positive value.  Then you could ignore the changes I recommended originally, above.

(You don't need to call `int()` because `count` is already of type `int`, as is `fcount`.)

Comment: I'm still learning. How would I use with var countValue:int = 3300000;

Answer (score 0):

why not setting the Timer.repeatCount to 3300000 ?

Comment: Please explain. Wouldn't that just repeat after 33 thousand seconds?

Comment: no. that means that the timer will tick 33 thousands times. The first parameter in the constructor is the time between two ticks

Answer (score 0):

In your code simply change:

```
var fraction:int = Math.abs(i % 100); 
var whole:int = Math.abs(i / 100);

("0000000" + whole).substr(-**5**, 7)
```

Comment: ("0000000" + whole).substr(-**7**, 7) is fine , I just saw you wanted the other two 0 there